# Laravel 4 Form builder Custom Fields Macro

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, php-5.3, laravel-4

Im trying to create a custom HTML 5 date field for using in a laravel 4 framework view.

```
{{
    Form::macro('datetime', function($field_name)
    { 
        return '';
    });         
}}

{{ Form::label('event_start', 'Event Date', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
{{ Form::datetime('event_start') }}
```

The only problem is the value is not being populated, and i do not know how to do this.

Im using this form to create and edit a model called Event.

how can i populate the value of this field?

Comment: Do you have any more code in your macro?  Have a look at how the [FormBuilder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L197-219) already does this kind of thing.  Also, blade tags are not the right place for macros to be defined.

Comment: Ya im aware blade tags are a bad place to define macros. Although im just tryin to get it working. I ended up using Form::input() as a workaround.

i will come back and post more details in a little while.

Thank you for your help though! :-)

Comment: Where would be the right place to define the macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I did:

in my view I added the following macro

```
<?php
Form::macro('datetime', function($value) {
    return '<input type="datetime" name="my_custom_datetime_field" value="'.$value.'"/>';
});
...
...
// here's how I use the macro and pass a value to it
{{ Form::datetime($datetime) }}
```

Answer (score 10):

I added in app/start/global.php the following:

```
Form::macro('date', function($name, $value = null, $options = array()) {
    $input =  '<input type="date" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '"';

    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $input .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $value . '"';
    }

    $input .= '>';

    return $input;
});
```

But the "good way" would be to extend the Form class and implement your methods.

Answer (score 4):

Using a macro is not necessary. Just use Laravel's built-in [`Form::input`](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html#method_input) method defining `date` as your desired input type:

```
{{ Form::label('event_start', 'Event Date', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
{{ Form::input('date', 'event_start', $default_value, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

This appears not to be in the main docs but is in the API docs as linked above.

Comment: There is a reason to use macros... saying "don't use this" in a question that specific ask it, it's kind of pointless

Comment: My answer has clearly helped some people as evidenced by its upvotes. OP doesn't specifically say he must use a macro, but that he wants a date input, which is achievable without needing a macro. I'm not sure what your comment adds to the discussion. SO is not just about blindly answering questions but sometimes suggesting alternative approaches that haven't been thought of.

Comment: As you said, it helped some people, I didn't down-vote you because you aren't **wrong**, but I comment to point out a specific point. Don't be offended. Thanks for your help to the community and keep the good work. And as you said, SO nor any SE site is to blind do anything. I pointed a specific point to help others that reach your question.

Answer (score 3):

I've found another way to do this which is putting my macros in a file named `macros.php` then place it under `app/` directory along with `filters.php` and `routs.php`, then in the `app/start/global.php` I added the following line at the end

```
require app_path().'/macros.php';
```

this will load your macros after the app has started and before the view is constructed. 
it seamed neater and following the Laravel's convention because this is the same way Laravel uses to load the `filters.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
Form::macro('date', function($name, $value = null, $options = array()) {
$attributes = HTML::attributes($options);
$input =  '<input type="date" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '"'. $attributes.'>';
return $input;
});
```

instead of doing

```
    foreach($options)
```

you can use

```
    HTML::attributes($options)
```