# creating a form field populated by a relationship in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to build a form for a Happening. The Happening references a Places table by `place_id`.

e.g. happening "OktoberFest" has a place_id 123 which corresponds in table Places to München

These are the relationships declared in the models:

For model Place:

```
public function happenings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Happening');
}
```

For model Happening:

```
public function place()
{
return $this->belongsTo('Place');
}
```

model Happening has a place_id field linking it to Place.

I am also using `{{Form::model($happening, array('route' => array('happenings.update', $happening->id)...}}` as form opening

**Problem 1:** how to create a `{{Form::text('......')}}` that will be properly prefilled with München when editing the happening Oktoberfest ?

**Problem 2:** I was trying to get that field to work as an ajax autosuggest (i.e. starting to pull suggestions from the Places table as soon as 3 characters have been entered). I have checked a few implementations but they don't seem to mix correctly with **Problem 1**

To try and solve **Problem 1**, I have tried  the solution here
[Laravel 4 Form builder Custom Fields Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259488/laravel-4-form-builder-custom-fields-macro)

but I was unable to make it work.

Long question, it's my very first on stack overflow, please be patient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Happening is linked to Place via the column 'place_id' you have to supply an id to save in your model/table.
There are a couple of ways that I can think of:

- make a list of availble Places in a radio of select, the name will be 'place_id', the value the id of the Place en something like title for the value.
- instead of displaying radio's or a select a textfield with autocomplete is a great solution if you got a lot of places. I won't go into detail how to implement it but the general idea is to autocomplete the typed in placename and on selection of that place to put the id of that place in a hidden field named 'placed_id'

After saving the form save your model with the posted place_id
(and check that id if it's valid and existing, never trust user input )

Comment: Rob, thanks. Since the places are around 45000, one of the next steps would have been to implement the autocomplete. I slept on it and I came to a similar solution to yours.

Now I need to tackle the ajax-bootstrap autocomplete (not very expert on that, but it seems that there are a few tuts around) and make sure to properly populate that field ..

Thanks again

Comment: Thanks again. I also found this http://fusiongrokker.com/post/heavily-customizing-a-bootstrap-typeahead that looks also very complete. I'll dig into both this weekend.