# How do I add HTML 5 type attribute to laravel blade?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this line in blade format

```
{{ Form::text('date', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'Date', 'placeholder' => 'Date' )) }}
```

but when the page loads the type attribute does not get resolved to 'date', it goes to 'text'.

How do I get this in blade?

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="Date" name="date">
```

Comment: You need to create a Form macro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259488/laravel-4-form-builder-custom-fields-macro

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Form::input()](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#202-233)

```
Form::input('date', 'date', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Date']);
```

Additionally, you can create a [Form Macro](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros) to "add" methods for HTML5 attributes, such as `date`, `email`, `time`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but have you try changing `Form::text` to `Form::date`?

Answer (score 1):

With Laravel 5.1, I am using this for date field.

```
{!! Form::date('start_date', null, ['class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12', 'placeholder' => 'Date']); !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also a couple composer/packagist packages you can quickly install to use HTML5 elements the same way as `text`, `email`, and `url` (eg: `Form::date('myDateField')`)

Here's one: https://github.com/smalldogs/html5inputs